# Netsuite - Customize Bill Sales Order form

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

is there anyway to customize or add SuiteScript to the Bill Sales Order form or any other form like the Fulfill Order form where the customization option isn't available?

Answer (score 1):

Those forms are not customisable in NetSuite.

However, you can create similar functionalities using Suitelet Scripts.